# What has been the evolution or progression of traitor/betrayal/defector games?

Tags: history

What has been the evolution of games with a traitor/betrayal/defector element? I remember what seemed like decades ago mention of party games like Mafia, Assassin, and as I re-enter the tabletop arena, I see a number of games like Resistance, Werewolf, Battlestar Galactica, Dead of Winter.

Does someone have an interesting historical perspective on the evolution of these games and their mechanics starting from whenever they may have gained momentum, showed similar or copycat mechanics, started branching into different mutations of the mechanic?

Comment: This seems like a discussion topic rather than a question that will work well in this format.

Comment: I'm having trouble distinguishing the differences between what's Q/A versus discussion, or too broad for SE. How would asking for details on traitor games in the past and their differences be much different, than, say, a recent question asking what games end with some winning, some losing, and some neither at all? Both feel like they are grounded in a 'what kind of games are there that ___' sort of vein. If I can clarify or adjust this question in a helpful way or if you can explain the differences between these two questions, that'd be great.

Comment: For what its worth, I'm not a fan of that question either.  I feel like the only thing saving it right now is that the answer is "No", and even that seems like a weak argument for it.

Comment: I think the general problem with this question is that there is no problem you are trying to solve.  You're just looking for general thoughts on a wide range of topics.  I can't come up with a suggestion to adjust the question because I'm unsure what you're trying to get out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These days Mafia is renowned as the worst game in the mafia genre.  The unifying element behind all of these is the hidden information about player allegiance.  It was an interesting mechanic in mafia, but the issue with mafia was that it had player elimination, so players spent a statistical third of the game sitting around doing nothing.  Another issue with mafia is that it was really only good with large numbers of players.  Board game designers being who they are adapted the hidden team mechanic to create better behaved versions of mafia, or include mafia like elements in various games.

Games like Resistance, Avalon, One Night Werewolf, Two Rooms and a Boom, etc. are all trying to address the fundamental problem that mafia had a great concept with a rather poor implementation of it.  (Werewolf proper is just a mafia reskin.)

Games like Battlestar the Boardgame and Shadows over Camelot are trying to include this in a set of broader mechanics to have the game have more intrigue than just a fully cooperative game (such as Pandemic) or a many vs. one game (such as Descent).